# How to type email symbol in word and Mac?

Tags: email

I'm facing a little issue and could use some assistance. I need to type the email symbol in both Microsoft Word and on my Mac computer, but I'm not sure how to do it. Can anyone provide me with a step-by-step guide or keyboard shortcut to easily insert the [✉ symbol](https://howtotypesymbols.com/envelope-email-symbol/)?

Comment: How did you type it in the question?

Comment: @Bravo - presumably copy/pase from the web page.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, ✉️ isn't 'email' it's just 'envelope'.
Email has an E in it -

However, there are a few ways you can access those, or any other emoji on Mac.
Simplest if you don't need to do this frequently is to call up the Emoji & Symbols panel. this comes in two versions, switchable using the small icon top right.

[image] [image]

There are different ways to call this up, depending on what OS & Mac you're on, the Globe  key or  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>   <kbd>Space</kbd>   - more details at [How to use macOS’s Character Viewer to type emoji and other symbols](https://www.macworld.com/article/607237/character-viewer-macos.html)

After that, just type mail in the search box & you can click [simple viewer] or double click [full Character Viewer] to insert the symbol at your current cursor position.

if this is something you're going to use a lot, then it might be worth setting up a text replacement. Again, this has changed where the setting is accessed in recent OSes, but the functionality is still the same. Here you can see I've added quick text replacements for a few emojis

[image]

I can now trigger the smiley by typing `.sml`

Comment: For windows, one can press WIN+. and select it using the popup.